# "Can't get attributes of file" error when downloading file using WinSCP .NET assembly

Tags: c#, winscp, winscp-net

I am working with WinSCP .NET library to transfer files from Linux to Windows.
I have a code but files are not getting downloaded.

Can someone look into this code and see what am I doing wrong.

In my view some problem is occurring in code line beginning with `transferResult`.

My Code :

```
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
    HostName = "sj1slm612",
    UserName = "username",
    Password = "password",
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 fa:e9:58:24:1b:41:a3:15:63:0d:c0:72:41:5d:51:7a"
};

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    // Connect
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    // Download Files

    TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
    transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;

    TransferOperationResult transferResult;
    transferResult = session.GetFiles("/apps/instances/sj1slm612/express_13000/configuration/standalone-full.xml", "C:\\Users\\karansha\\Desktop\\sj1slm612\\express_13000", false, transferOptions);
    transferResult = session.GetFiles("/apps/instances/sj1slm612/query_13100/configuration/standalone-full.xml", "C:\\Users\\karansha\\Desktop\\sj1slm612\\query_13100", false, transferOptions);
    transferResult = session.GetFiles("/apps/instances/sj1slm612/wppapi_13200/configuration/standalone-full.xml", "C:\\Users\\karansha\\Desktop\\sj1slm612\\wppapi_13200", false, transferOptions);
    transferResult = session.GetFiles("/apps/instances/sj1slm612/wppgui_13300/configuration/standalone-full.xml", "C:\\Users\\karansha\\Desktop\\sj1slm612\\wppgui_13300", false, transferOptions);

    // Throw Error
    transferResult.Check();

    Console.WriteLine("All Files Downloaded");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Error message is:

> Can't get attributes of file '/apps/instances/sj1slm612/wppgui_13300/configuration/standalone-full.xml'.

Comment: Do you get any error? if so can you post?

Comment: Yes error message: Can't get attributes of file '/apps/instances/sj1slm612/wppgui_13300/configuration/standalone-full.xml'.

Comment: does the file exist? do you have the neccessary rights to read it?

Comment: Yes, i have full rights/permissions and file also exists on the same Linux server path i mentioned in code.

Comment: There is normally another line to the error eg `No such file or directory` or `access denied`, do you get anything else?

Comment: Can you please check if some issue is occurring in line : transferResult

Comment: Yes, you are right actually Linux directory was invalid. Thanks for pointing it out. Issue resolved.

Comment: You have to call `TransferOperationResult.Check` after every call to `Session.GetFiles`. + The destination path needs to end with backslash (if it is a path to a destination directory). See http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfiles

Comment: Also you should close this question, if it is resolved. Ideally post a solution yourself. Thanks.